# Opening pdf file in C# form

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

How can I open a pdf file in a c# form?

I don't want use Acrobat, because I want to limit users for printing or accessing my original pdf files.I just want them to see a list files (pdf) and select the file and view it on a form.

Comment: have you tried anything yet?

Comment: Windows forms or aspx forms?

Comment: You could use the Adobe Acrobat PDF Reader control on your Winform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this option

copy pdf file content in to textfile and textfile you can easily merge inside form....

Answer (score 0):

Use a thrid-party library, for example [pdflib](http://pdflib.codeplex.com/). It will allow you to configure what users can do

Answer (score 0):

You can easily open the PDF usign `WebBrowser control`. Add a webBrowser control to your Winform. Add the following method to your form.

```
private void OpenPdf(string filePath)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath))
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(@filePath);
    }
}
```

`Call the method within button click`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenPdf(@"C:\Users\kkk\Downloads\DEF2236.pdf");
}
```

Comment: I think this will not support printing using form buttons